# Swift can't use protocol from framework

Tags: swift, frameworks

I create simple framework in Swift that contain public protocol. I did add it to my project, added import, and try to add variable to my class that is actually a protocol that my framework declare.
However, i got an error:

```
 Use of undeclared type 'PaymentTerminal'
```

I declare it like this:

```
public protocol PaymentTerminal: class {

}
```

In my class, i add import my framework :

```
import PaymentTerminalInterface
```

Then try to:

```
var terminal: PaymentTerminal!
```

And got an error i describe above.

When i try to cmd+press on `PaymentTerminal` in `var terminal: PaymentTerminal!` i successfully dig in protocol declaration.

Comment: Its working for me. Did you try clean-build?

Comment: use `open` instead of `public` and try again

Comment: @PuneetSharma tried to many times.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: How are you adding framework in your project? While adding choose copy and create references.

Comment: @PuneetSharma yes i did add and succesfully import module without compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed after i change deployment iOS target version in my framework to same as in my app.